# I don't want to see messages from a member of a WhatsApp group

Tags: whatsapp

I participate in a WhatsApp group with several people.

In this group, there is that annoying person who sends "Good morning" messages every single day...

1. This person is not in my contacts
2. The group is muted.
3. I'm not the Admin.

But I always have to skip these unnecessary messages from this participant.

Is there any way to "filter" out messages from this specific participant?

Comment: Are you using a desktop, mobile or web version of WhatsApp? Please [edit] the tags on the question.

Comment: The problem is the same regardless of platform.

Comment: It's not possible given your restrictions. Politely ask them not to do it.